# DOM correction as an alternative to a "XML interleaving algorithm", it is always valid?

Tags: xml, algorithm, dom, xhtml

This question was not simple and objective.

Question migrated to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/200965/84349

Comment: jsFiddle doesn't actually support XHTML. As the names of all the methods imply, you're working with HTML throughout the script. Nowhere are you dealing with XHTML or XML.

Comment: No, it can be XHTML: I edited, see the "saveXML ideia".

Comment: ... Migrating question to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/200965/84349